# Have rsync respect btrfs copy-on-write files

Tags: rsync, btrfs

Is it possible to have rsync respect copy-on-write files from filesystems like btrfs?

I've been trying some tests of syncing a 1GB file and a copy-on-write clone of this file (so 1GB shared between them) from one btrfs fs to another but rsync will send 2GB of data and when I do `btrfs filesystem du` on the received files there are 0 bytes shared. So rsync is just creating a new copy rather than a CoW copy on the receiving end.

Comment: Don't know, but I would ask on the rsync list. They are very knowledgeable and helpful and the developers frequently answer as well. https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/rsync

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature that `rsync` currently supports.

However, you could work around this in a few ways:

- Let rsync transfer both files, then deduplicate them on the remote end with a btrfs deduplication tool.
- Place the files on their own btrfs subvolume, and use `btrfs send` with `btrfs receive`.
- `rsync` one of the files, create a clone of it, then use `--checksum --inplace --no-whole-file` to force rsync to patch the second file with just the differences from the first file.